# BeautifulSoup similar for C#

Tags: c#, python, beautifulsoup

is there any similar library to `BeautifulSoup` for `C#`?

I want to simply parse HTMLs and XMLs, specially HTMLs with errors.

Comment: I've used this briefly before (about 5/6 years ago!?) http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ and it was okay for what I needed - but never had to extensively test it or put it through its paces...

Comment: http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader 
I've used this in the past to parse HTML. It's been pretty reliable with pretty questionable HTML

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have used [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) in the past with some success but it had some issues with parsing HTML that is badly formed or missing closing tags.  However that was about 2 years ago.

I have usually tended toward the [SGMLReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader) which allows you to wrap it with a XML Reader and so you can then easily use XDocument or XmlDocument in C# to read the HTML.  The SGMLReader has worked on all malformed HTML that I have thrown at it.